# Plot sub-sections of Pandas Dataframes in Python - all legend entries in one column

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, plot

I have the following Pandas DataFrame in Python 2.7.

```
 Name        Date   Val_Celsius Rm_Log
 Lite  2012-07-17            77     12
 Lite  2012-12-01            76    -21
 Lite  2012-09-01            79     73
 Lite  2013-12-01            78    945
Staed  2012-07-17           105     36
Staed  2012-12-01           104     19
Staed  2012-09-01           102    107
Staed  2013-12-01           104     11
ArtYr  2012-07-17           -11    100
ArtYr  2012-12-01           -14     21
ArtYr  2012-09-01           -10     68
ArtYr  2013-12-01           -12     83
```

I need to plot the `Rm_Log` numbers as the y-variable and I need to plot the `Date` as the x-variable.

However, I need there to be 3 separate overlapping plots on the same figure - 1st plot for `Lite`, 2nd for `Staed` and 3rd for `ArtYr`. I need the legend for the figure to show 3 entries, **Lite**, **Staed** and **ArtYr**.

I have never done a plot like this before. Usually, I have separate columns but here the numbers are arranged differently.

If I create 3 separate DataFrames for each `Name` then it is possible to plot. However, the `Name` column typically has a lot more entries than just the 3 that I have shown so this method is very time consuming. Also, the number of entries are not known ahead of time.i.e. here I have shown 3 entries, `Lite`, `Staed` and `ArtYr`, but there may be 50 or there may be 100 entries. I cannot create 50-100 DataFrames each time I need to generate one figure.

How can I show overlapping plots of the `Rm_Log` vs `Date` column, for each `Name` value, on the same figure? Is it possible to get the date as vertical on the x-axis?

EDIT:
Error I get when using ax.set_ticks(df.index):

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 2602, in set_xticks
    return self.xaxis.set_ticks(ticks, minor=minor)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1574, in set_ticks
    self.set_view_interval(min(ticks), max(ticks))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1885, in set_view_interval
    max(vmin, vmax, Vmax))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\transforms.py", line 973, in _set_intervalx
    self._points[:, 0] = interval
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 2012-07-17
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use anything besides native pandas, you can still do this pretty easily:

```
df.reset_index().set_index(["Name", "Date"]).unstack("Name")["Rm_Log"].plot(rot=90)
```

First, you sort it using a MultiIndex, then you unstack it so that each entry in the Name column becomes its own column.  Then you select the Rm_Log column and plot it.  The argument `rot=90` rotates the xticks.  You could also separate this into several lines, but I thought I'd keep it as one to show how it could be done without modifying the DataFrame.

Comment: A couple of questions. 1. The second last line (`ax.set_xticks(df.index)`) does not seem to work - if I leave it out, then it appears to be working. I have added this to the original post as an **EDIT**. 2. How do I save such a figure to a *.png file with a white background (currently Python gives grey background with white inside the axes - I just want white everywhere)?

Comment: For saving with appropriate background color: `ax.gcf.savefig('path/to/where/you/want/to/save.png', facecolor='w')`

Comment: I found a simpler method of rotating the ticks that should work.

Answer (score 0):

That is where `ggplot` inspired from `R` is absolutely amazing for simplicity, you do not have to modify your dataframe.

```
from ggplot import *

ggplot(df, aes(x='Date', y='Rm_log', color='Name')) + geom_line()
```